# How do I get billing activity status of a user via the slack api?

Tags: slack, slack-api

We have a slack app and in that app we would like to get billable users information for a particular slack team/workspace.

We can achieve this by using [team.billableInfo](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.billableInfo), but this API needs admin scope permission.
No one will allow us (a third party app) admin permission in his/her workspace, so we can not use this API.

Another way we thought to implement by using combination of [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) and [users.getPresence](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.getPresence) APIs.

[users.getPresence](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.getPresence) API returns `last_activity` which indicates the last activity seen by slack servers. We can compare `last_actvity` with current time to get the active users in a particular month for a slack workspace per Slack's Fair Billing policy.

But if a user has no connected clients then `last_activity` property is absent and that's why we can not use this combination also.

For our case many of our users have no connected clients and we want to get billable users count for this particular case.

Is there any other way we can try to get this billable users count of a particular slack workspace per Slack's Fair Billing policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, there are no such options provided by slack yet to get billable users count of a particular slack workspace per Slack's Fair Billing policy by a third party app, we trying to ignore this kind of counting and instead asking users to contact us if they feel they are treated unfairly.